# why doesn't python give me the option to close openCV window?

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have the following code that prints the following image. Why don't I have the option to close the window (small Red Cross missing in top left corner)?

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('/Users/natashabustnes/Desktop/geeks14.png')
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: you pressed a key, didn't you? then waitKey returned and the GUI is now longer responding to anything. run waitKey again (loop).

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by this. How do I make this close option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code displays window and waits for a keypress.
When you pressed a key, waitKey returned and the GUI froze because there's was no more instructions.
Do something like this instead.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('/Users/natashabustnes/Desktop/geeks14.png')
cv2.imshow('image', img)
while True:
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code waits until you press the 'q' button before closing.
OpenCV by default does not support closing windows using the normal close button.